# Updating and Invoicing Stripe Subscription Quantity with Invoice description laravel cashier

Tags: php, laravel, stripe-payments, laravel-cashier

Good Day,

I'm working on a project involving Laravel Cashier. I want to give user's the ability to update their subscription quantity and get charged immediately (which I have been able to achieve, using the code below)

```
$user = Auth::user()
$user->subscription('main')->incrementAndInvoice(10000);
```

As much as the above works as expected, the invoice returned doesn't include a description indicating the changes instead the invoice description is blank. But when I checked the Event Data on stripe the two descriptions are there [see below image]

[image: First Description which is the user's current/unused quantity]
[image]

The above images shows a user who was currently on a subscription plan with 5000 quantities but increased to 15000 quantities. Is there a way to include these descriptions in the invoice generated.

After i checked the `incrementAndInvoice()` method , it only accepts two parameter (1. count, 2. Plan) as seen below;

[image]

no option to include description like we have for the `charge()` method. Is there any workaround to this? Any ideas or pointers in the right direction would be really appreciated.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Try with `$invoice = $subscription->asStripeSubscription(['latest_invoice']);`
`$invoice->description`

Answer (score 0):

At the time being there is no implementation to include the description in `incrementAndInvoice()`.

So we have to implement it and before we do that please checkout [Update an invoice](https://stripe.com/docs/api/invoices/update).

First change this line: `$user->subscription('main')->incrementAndInvoice(10000);` to `$subscription = $user->subscription('main')->incrementAndInvoice(10000);` (we are assigning it to `$subscription` variable)

then get the invoice as below:

```
$new_invoice = $user->invoices()->filter(function($invoice) use ($subscription) {
   return $invoice->subscription === $subscription->stripe_id;
});
```

After updating the subscription quantity we will add the following:

```
$client  = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
$request = $client->post('https://api.stripe.com/v1/invoices/' . $invoice_id, [
    'auth' => [$secret_key, null]
    'json' => ['description' => 'your description']
]);

$response = json_decode($request->getBody());
```

Or the following:

```
$stripe = new \Stripe\StripeClient(
  $secret_key
);
$stripe->invoices->update(
  $invoice_id,
  ['description' => 'your description']
);
```

**Please note that:**

- the `$invoice_id` is the id of the invoice.
- the `$secret_key` is the API key.

Comment: Thanks for your response. The thing is, there is no access to invoice ID because the invoice is sent back from stripe when a subscription quantity is updated and the user is charged immediately (which is called `IncrementAndInvoice()` )

Comment: what do you get when you do like this `dd($user->subscription('main')->incrementAndInvoice(10000));`

Comment: i get subscription table data for the user and the change in quantity .... nothing regarding invoice. https://ibb.co/wg0LLHr and https://ibb.co/z7Tm3SS

Comment: checkout the updated answer ... please checkout this link https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/getting-invoicereceipt-of-selected-subscription-plan?page=0 for more info

Comment: Invoice came in still with no description https://ibb.co/5Mq14sr

Comment: can you please share the new code that you use now ?

Comment: This is what i added to the line ... https://ibb.co/FnqLmbv ... The thing is the invoice is being prepared and returned by stripe and its added to the payment history table. If i subscribe to a plan, the invoice works fine with all the description but when i update quantity and invoice, the description is not included

Comment: Ok before return response add the following '''$client  = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
$request = $client->post('https://api.stripe.com/v1/invoices/' . $new_invoice->id, [
    'auth' => [$secret_key, null]
    'json' => ['description' => 'your description']
]);

$response = json_decode($request->getBody());'''